# Errors during apt-get update

Tags: synaptic

Software center and synaptics got broken somehow. I seem to have it fixed through sourses.list  but I'm getting errors when I run `sudo apt-get update`.

(Screenshot will be coming soon)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While we would like to help you, this is an English-only site, and as such, your question will most likely be closed. If you can edit your question to be asked in English or ask a new question in English, that would be great :)

Comment: команда *программа (команда) apt-get update выдаёт кучу ошибок

Comment: @Rinzwind I'll handle this , don't worry

Comment: @Zacharee1 it's russian

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/dkkikb64j/

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/8dqeknycb/